# dijit.byId not working(is not a function?)

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

This is my simple dojo example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/themes/dijit.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<title>ShowMovies </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(
    [ "dojo", "dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
            "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
            "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore" ],
    function(dojo) {
        dojo.ready(function() {
            dojo.xhrGet( {
                url : "MovieList.json",
                handleAs : "json",
                load : function(response, ioArgs) {
                    var newData = {
                        identifier: "title",
                        items: response.result
                    };
                    var dataStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: newData, id:"dataStoreId"});
                    var grid = dijit.byId("gridId");
                    grid.setStore(dataStore);
                },
                error : function(response, ioArgs) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css">
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="BorderContainer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer"
        data-dojo-props="design:'headline'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region:'top'" style="text-align: center">My Movie Web Application!</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
            <table id="gridId" autowidth="true"
                data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid"
                data-dojo-props="rowSelector:'20px'">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th field="title">Title</th>
                        <th field="director">Director</th>
                        <th field="actor">Actor</th>
                        <th field="description">Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region:'right'"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why do I receive an error for the xhrGet request? The response is: **dijit.byid is not a function**

Thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The quick answer is: When you have `async:true` in your Dojo config, you should probably not have anything in your Javascript code that starts with `dojo.` or `dijit.`.

Back in the old days, in Dojo 1.5 and earlier, Dojo and its modules worked a little differently than they do today.

At that time, you could include dojo.js and immediately have a range of handy functions available, such as `dojo.create`, `dojo.connect`, `dojo.xhrGet`, `dijit.byId` and many many more. If you wanted to include some additional module or widget, you'd use `dojo.require` and then reference the module with `dojo.some.thing` or `dijit.other.thing`.

In newer versions of Dojo, when you include dojo.js on your page, you effectively only get two functions: `require` and `define`. You use these functions to "import" everything you need. Even for something as small as `dojo.create`, you have to import a module.

In the beginning, you'll probably find this very inconvenient. If you're interested in why Dojo has taken this direction and the benefits of it, you can check out this [slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/sitepen/beyond-dojo-the-rise-of-asynchronous-module-definition-amd-12835213).

Back to your code. You have `async:true` and lots of `dojo.` and a `dijit.` statements. Here are 3 ways you can solve it:

1. Change `async:true` to false. This makes Dojo handle code in the "old" style, i.e. your `dojo.` and `dijit.` should still work.
2. Keep `async:true`, but import the special `dijit/dijit` module, which makes the old `dijit.` functions available. So your first line(s) would be something like this:

   `require(["dojo","dijit/dijit",....], function(dojo, dijit, ...) {`

   (The "dojo" module is also a special module to allow the "old" style.)
3. Rewrite your code to the new AMD style all over. That means for every `dojo.` and `dijit.`, you need to find out which module you need to import. It's going to be a bit of work if you already have a lot of Dojo code. The code in your question would look something like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/8DETs/

You may be thinking to yourself: Loading a file/module for every little thing must be very slow! And you are right. The idea is that when you develop locally, it will be fast enough, and when you deploy your web app, you'll use Dojo's build tool to create a lean package in very few files. This is one of Dojo's absolute strong points, you can read more about it here: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/build/